# MATCH command, using $currentMatch in WHILE to stop traversal

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I want to traverse a graph using match, but stop the traversal when a certain node is not connected to another specific node.

To clarify, I have the following setup:

[Setup of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muKFj.png)

My goal is to perform the following query:

**For a wall, give me all linked/deep properties of that wall that are part of the same commit as the wall, but only if the full path from property to wall is part of commit**

This means that, starting from commit #21:0, I go to wall #30:0, for which I should get 0 properties (note that property #34:0 is not linked to commit #21:0!), while starting from commit #22:0, would go to wall #29:0, for which I should get all 4 properties. Basically I want to stop the traversal of the `MATCH` whenever a node is hit which is not connected to the specified commit node.

I tried a `MATCH` command, with a `while` in which I check if there is a `shortestPath` from the commit to the `$currentMatch`. However, this doesn't seem to work, I get error that Vertex ID cannot be NULL.

My query is like:

```
select expand(ret) from (
    MATCH {class: V, as: commit, where:(@rid = #21:0)},
    {as: commit}.out("commitlink"){as: wall, where:(@class INSTANCEOF "Wall")},
    {as: wall}.out("E"){as: props, where:(@class = "Property"), while:(shortestPath($matched.commit, $currentMatch, "OUT","commitlink").size() > 0)}
  return items as ret)
```

... but note that this query gives a the "Vertex id can not be null" error.

I seem to misunderstand the availability of `$currentMatch` in the `while` part of the command.

EDIT:
This seems to do the job:

```
select expand($properties) LET 
$commit = (SELECT FROM #22:0),
$wall = (SELECT FROM (SELECT expand(out("commitlink")) FROM $commit) WHERE 
@class INSTANCEOF "Wall"),
$properties = (SELECT FROM (TRAVERSE OUT("E") FROM $wall WHILE (shortestPath($commit, @rid, "OUT", "commitlink").size() > 0)) WHERE @class INSTANCEOF "Property")
```

But is there a drawback in using traverse queries instead of MATCH?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get what you want but what I understood is that your query should return all the property that are directly connected to the commit vertex without a Wall in between, am I right?

If this is what you want, try this:

```
MATCH {class: Property, as: props}.in("commitlink"){as: commit, where:(@rid = #19:0)} return props
```

this is my schema:

[image]

this is the result:

[image]

Hoope it helps

Regards

Comment: This is not really what I mean. I changed my text of the example query. Basically I want all connected properties from a wall, but only those who's path from wall to property is connected to same commit as wall. What I'm trying is: from commit select wall -> from wall traverse out for properties in same commit -> stop deep traversal if property is not in commit, continue on other parts from wall